# How can I disable screensaver in Ubuntu 14.04 with icewm

Tags: 14.04, screensaver, xscreensaver, icewm

How can I disable screensaver?

I tried `xset s off`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Launch terminal using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` and run these command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
```

Comment: Won't this only work for GNOME's screensaver? (Its probably Xscreensaver or whatever IceWM uses)

Comment: dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=d8b0c3099c3b155b43a4f59d549a785e --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

Comment: Did you unable to run the command @KeyurVakharia ?

Comment: I didnt get u @FirstStrike

Comment: Did the command work ??